# Book recommendation regarding complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have just studied complex numbers from a standard text book for high school (NCERT in India), so I posess rudimentary knowledge of complex numbers, but I would like to brush up my basics again as well as gain knowledge of the tools required for olympiad level problems (not participating in one, but would like to solve such problems). Does anyone have recommendations for such books which I can use to both brush up my basics and learn and study a bit advanced level problem (along with proper explanation, ofcourse)? Also please recommend books limited to high school level (+ national olympiad level).

Your help would be really appreciated.

***THANKS***